# Faster way to calculate distance between two locations (ZIP codes)

Tags: performance, ms-access, vba

I am writing a VBA script that finds ZIP Codes inside of a specified radius. I have an Access Database with multiple records in a table. Each record has a Name, Address, and Zip Code field on the table. The VBA code on access prompts the user for a zip code and search radius then calculates the distance between the user input zip code and the zip code for each record. Once each distance is calculated the record is displayed to the form as long as it falls within the radius input field.

The code that I have written works but the execution time takes too long (around 30 secs for 2000ish records). How can I decrease the time it takes for this VBA code to run? Here is the code I have written:

```
Private Sub Command65_Click()
Dim StartTime As Double
Dim SecondsElapsed As Double
Dim i, j As Integer
Dim db As Database
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim ZIP, r As Double
Dim arr(33144, 3) As Double
Dim lat1, long1, lat2, long2, theta As Double
Dim Distance As Integer
Dim deg2rad, rad2deg As Double
Const PI As Double = 3.14159265359
'Dim Variables

StartTime = Timer
deg2rad = PI / 180
rad2deg = 180 / PI

r = Text1.Value
ZIP = Text2.Value
'Get radius and prompted zip code from form

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("US Zip Codes")
'Open the Table named "US Zip Codes"

For i = 0 To 33143
    arr(i, 0) = rs.Fields("ZIP")
    arr(i, 1) = rs.Fields("LAT")
    arr(i, 2) = rs.Fields("LNG")
    rs.MoveNext
Next i
'Loop through each Zip Code record and store the Zip Code, Lattitude Point, and Longitude Point to an array

For i = 0 To 33143
    If ZIP = arr(i, 0) Then
        lat1 = arr(i, 1) * deg2rad
        long1 = arr(i, 2) * deg2rad
    End If
Next i
'Loop through the zip code array to get Zip Code's corresponding LAT and LONG

Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Clinics")
'Open the Table named "Clinics"

For j = 0 To 2094
    If rs("Clinic ZIP") = ZIP Then
        Distance = 0
        'If Zip Code 1 and Zip Code 2 are equal to each other, Distance = 0
    ElseIf rs("Clinic ZIP") <> "" Then
        zip2 = rs("Clinic ZIP")
        For i = 0 To 33143
            If zip2 = arr(i, 0) Then
                lat2 = arr(i, 1) * deg2rad
                long2 = arr(i, 2) * deg2rad
            End If
        Next i
        'Loop through the zip code array to get the second Zip Code's corresponding LAT and LONG
        theta = long1 - long2
        Distance = ArcCOS(Sin(lat1) * Sin(lat2) + Cos(lat1) * Cos(lat2) * Cos(theta)) * rad2deg * 60 * 1.1515
        'Calculate Distance between the two zip codes
    Else
        Distance = 999
        'Set Arbitrary Value if the zip code field is empty
    End If
    rs.Edit
    rs.Fields("Distance") = Distance
    rs.Update
    rs.MoveNext
Next j

Me.Filter = "Distance<=" & r
Me.FilterOn = True
'Filter the table with calculated distance by prompted radius
Forms("Zip Search").Requery
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
db.Close

SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)
MsgBox "This code ran successfully in " & SecondsElapsed & " seconds", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Don't know whether it has performance impact but you can't dim multiple variables in one go; `Dim lat1, long1, lat2, long2, theta As Double`. Should read `Dim lat1 As Double, Dim long1 As Double, Dim lat2 as Double, Dim long2 As Double, Dimtheta As Double`

Comment: Same for this line of code, `Dim deg2rad, rad2deg As Double`. Should be `Dim deg2rad As Double, Dim rad2deg As Double`. Non-declared variables will get the default being Variant.

Comment: Why "33143"? This is a magic number that has no explanation in your code.

Comment: "Don't use VBA" is not an answer - but why not set up a calculated query? You get the source ZipCode from a text input.

Comment: Are ZipCodes strings or doubles? Hint: They should be strings as they are identifiers, not numbers.

Comment: @AJD Thanks for the help. 33143 is the number of zip codes I have in the table. Also I would set the program up as a calculated query but access does not have the built in functions I need

Comment: This screams out for update queries. Looping through 10's of thousands of records in an interpreted language is not a good idea when the DB engine is designed to do the same thing.

Comment: Preston: You build up the functions in a calculated field in the query. Check out the ExpressionBuilder that appears on a right click (context menu) when creating a table or query.

Comment: Is this a multi-user database? Multiple simultaneous users will conflict with each other writing Distance into table.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just did a test with a table of 1,976 restaurant locations:

```
ID  lon        lat       poi_name                                     
--  ---------  --------  ---------------------------------------------
 1   -114.063   51.0466  Palomino Smokehouse: Calgary, AB             
 2   -114.055   51.0494  Bookers BBQ Grill and Crab Shack: Calgary, AB
 3  -86.97871  34.58037  Big Bob Gibson's Original: Decatur, AL       
 4  -87.01763  34.56587  Big Bob Gibson's #2: Decatur, AL             
 5    -86.364  32.26995  DJ's Old Post Office: Hope Hull, AL          
...
```

Using the `GreatCircleDistance` function available from ...

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/LatLong.aspx

... I ran the following query to calculate the distance from a given point

```sql
PARAMETERS prmLon IEEEDouble, prmLat IEEEDouble;
SELECT BBQ2.ID, BBQ2.lon, BBQ2.lat, BBQ2.poi_name, 
    GreatCircleDistance([prmLat],[prmLon],[lat],[lon],True,False) AS km
FROM BBQ2;
```

and the results came back in less than a second.

Then to return results within a certain number of kilometers from a given point I used

```sql
PARAMETERS prmLon IEEEDouble, prmLat IEEEDouble, prmWithinKm IEEEDouble;
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT BBQ2.ID, BBQ2.lon, BBQ2.lat, BBQ2.poi_name, 
        GreatCircleDistance([prmLat],[prmLon],[lat],[lon],True,False) AS km
    FROM BBQ2
)
WHERE km <= [prmWithinKm];
```

and again, the results came back in less than a second.

Comment: Access can process about 100,000 records in one second. I like your approach. I was about to suggest that a query updates the table with the distance, and then query on that. A UDF() in a query is certainly slower (100x), but I think with performance, your approach eliminates the need for a temp table. Up-voted!

Answer (score 2):

Applying comments to revise code, consider following which assumes ArcCos() is a public custom UDF. Also, two query objects are referenced as data sources. One is a query of the ZipCodes table which calculates the lat and long values. The other is a query that joins Clinics table to the above query.

```
Private Sub Command65_Click()
Dim StartTime As Double
Dim lat1 As Double, long1 As Double
Dim Distance As Integer
'Dim Variables

StartTime = Timer

lat1 = DLookup("lat", "qryLatLongZip", "Zip='" & Me.Text2 & "'")
long1 = DLookup("long", "qryLatLongZip", "Zip='" & Me.Text2 & "'")

CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE qryClinicsLatLongZip SET Distance = ArcCos(Sin(" & lat1 & ") * Sin(lat) + Cos(" & lat1 & ") * Cos(lat) * Cos(" & long1 & "-long)) * (180 / 3.14159265359) * 60 * 1.1515"

Me.Filter = "Distance<=" & Me.Text1
Me.FilterOn = True
'Filter the form with calculated distance by prompted radius

MsgBox "This code ran successfully in " & Round(Timer - StartTime, 2) & " seconds", vbInformation

End Sub
```

However, in a multi-user database, users will conflict with each other writing Distance to shared table. If there are multiple users then db would have to be split and a temp table (table is permanent, records are temporary) in frontend for writing records to and that would be report RecordSource. A solution avoiding record edit/saving would be most desirable and now I see an answer has been provided doing exactly that.